# Why do these parentheses give different answers in C?

Tags: c, cs50, parentheses, arithmetic-expressions, integer-division

I was working on readability for CS50 PS 2, and was getting incorrect outputs on the grade level.

Debugging showed that the input values were correct, but the output was wrong. Hand calculating using the inputs gave the correct answer.

I simplified the first part of the equation and found this:

Using the values of `214` for `L` and `56` for `W`, the expression:

```
float R = (0.0588 * (L / W) * 100);
```

outputs `17.64`, which is wrong.

When I use:

```
float R = (0.0588 * L / W * 100);
```

it outputs `22.47`, which is correct.

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
float R = (0.0588 * (L / W) * 100);
```

will develop to

```
float R = 0,0588 * 3 * 100;
```

which is `17.64`, when rounded to two decimal places.

The result of `L / W` [integer division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/6865932) is an `int`, so the result `3.8...` will be truncated to `3`.

To correct this, at least one of the variables `W` or `L` must be of type `float` or `double`.

The expression

```
float R = (0.0588 * L / W * 100);
```

will develop to

```
float R = ((0,0588 * 214) / 24) * 100 //parenthesis to illustrate the sequence
```

which outputs the correct result, `22.47`, when rounded to two decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Chances are good that both `L` and `W` is declared as `int`. Then in the first case, `(L/W)` will also be treated as an `int`, and therefore is floored, which causes the error.

Side note: even if they are declared `float` or `double`, floating point arithmetics means multiplication and division is not associative.